# How to get my process' id (PID) in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

How to get my process' id (PID) in Android NDK?

```
jclass proc_Cls = env->FindClass("android/os/Process");
jmethodID proc_id = env->GetMethodID(proc_Cls, "myPid", "()I");
jint prcId = env->CallIntMethod(proc_Cls, proc_id);
```

This code does not work.

Comment: What does this code return?

Comment: @BilltheLizard - what it returns is beside the point, as that's really not a good solution to the problem anyway, though it does establish that the poster tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a process ID is an operating system level identifier, it makes much more sense in C or C++ to discover it from the operation system than to try to get it from the Android stack through "reverse" JNI.

The posix function for obtaining the process ID is

```
pid_t getpid(void);
```

To use it you must first

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

As it's a posix function it should work not only atop a Linux kernel, but also on top of anything that Android is likely to be ported to run on.  If there's a portability concern, it's with the very idea of wanting to know the PID / assuming that this is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

```
jclass process = env->FindClass("android/os/Process");
jmethodID my_pid_id = env->GetStaticMethodID(process, "myPid", "()I");
int pid = env->CallStaticIntMethod(process, my_pid_id);
```

Process.myPid() is a static method, you need call with static version method to get it.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**